# What resources can I use to validate a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

What resources are available to validate a DTD? I want to be clear: I am not talking about validating XML documents against a DTD.

I am talking about making sure that the DTD itself is valid.

Comment: Any conforming XML parser can be used to check that a DTD conforms to the rules in the XML spec (which is, I assume, what you mean by 'valid' -- DTDs cannot be valid in the sense defined in the XML spec because they aren't XML document instances.  Open-source XML validators include xmllint (built on libxml), rxp, and Xerces.

Comment: Try to validate your XML documents against a DTD that forgets a closing > sign. The results of using that DTD to check XML documents would be a disaster. If you do not want to call an incomplete DTD invalid then what would you call that?

Comment: Broken, wrong, incorrect, syntactically incorrect, non-conforming, faulty, all of these are fine clear terms that don't conflict with the definitions assigned to terms by the spec.  There is no need to try to press the term "valid"  into service here:  it has its own meaning, which is important enough to be careful about.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen It is _valid_ to use the term "invalid" as a catch-all for all those other terms you've listed - the question is how to determine a DTD document is valid against the DTD standard/spec

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. [Validome](http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate) is a free, online DTD and Schema validator. It does not require me to sign up for any trials, or install any frameworks or other software in order to validate a DTD. Hope this helps someone else. Cheers.

Comment: It appears that Validome is no longer online. Does anyone know of any other online DTD validators?

Comment: Try https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp or https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: Both of those suggestions seem to validate XML against a DTD or XSD document. However, I don't see any way to test the DTD to make sure it is correct and well-formed.

Comment: @AlanKrause did you found any tool about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet No, I did not.

Answer (score 7):

You are able to validate DTD files using the eclipse java IDE. I realise it is not a lightweight solution, however I found it useful whilst working with DTDs which would eventually be compiled to Java classes via xjc.

To do this you can load the .dtd file in eclipse (copy it into a project, or point your project towards your dtd file). Then in the file navigator in eclipse, you can right click on the dtd, then click validate.

[For documentation see the Eclipse official website](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.dtdeditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftvaldtd.html)

Answer (score 2):

I work with Oxygen xml editor, you can try for 30 day trial!
Works very well with xml files, dtd, xslt...
When you write DTD code you can validate it (document menu > validate).
The dtd file is an xml file which describe a xml file. 
This code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title, paragraph)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT paragraph (#PCDATA)>
```

are valid.
This code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title, paragraph)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT paragraph (strong)>
```

give an alert.
hope it work for you

Comment: Anything free like the w3c's HTML validator: http://validator.w3.org? I don't want to spend hundreds of dollars for this.

Comment: @Tarzan I see no option to upload a dtd?