# Is there a DTD for the DTD?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd, sgml

I am writing a DTD and I think it would be nice to know, if it is valid. For that, I need the DTD (description) of the DTD (document type).

Does it exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What resources can I use to validate a DTD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984426/what-resources-can-i-use-to-validate-a-dtd)

Comment: @NathanHughes No, it is a general question and mine is specific: it wants resources, I want formal description. I am also lesser interested in the actually used tool.

Comment: There is a grammar for DTDs in the XML recommendation, but the grammar is not written as a DTD because DTDs are not XML instances. Validation of DTDs is made much more complicated by the rules for parameter entities. The way to validate that a DTD is correct is to process an XML document using a good validating XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the DTD (description) of the DTD (document type).

No, a DTD for DTDs does not exist.  DTDs are designed to describe XML, and DTDs are not XML. You may be thinking of an [XSD for XSD](https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd), which is viable because XSDs are XML.

> I want [a] formal description.

A [formal description of DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-doctype) in [EBNF notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-notation) is included in the [formal specification of XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/).

Comment: Their syntax is very XML.

Comment: @peterh:  Not sure I understand your comment.  What's the referent of your *their* there?  XSD syntax is XML; DTD is not.

Comment: I think it is practically xml. It is just full of `<!SOMETHING>` things. I think it is like a comment or some meta-rule in the XML world. So would it be very logical. Maybe it is not xml as the standard, but in this case, I believe, the xml standard is not complete.

Comment: @peterh: There's a superficial resemblance between `<!SOMETHING>` in a DTD and the `<![ ... ]>` CDATA or `<!-- ... -->` comments in XML markup, but in no practical sense is the DTD syntax "practically" XML.  Contrast the syntax of DTD with that of XSD, where XML itself is formally used to specify the vocabulary and grammar of XML documents.